# Determining box-box intersection without cross product

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Does anyone know a way to correctly determine if an axis-aligned box intersects with an oriented (using any invertible square matrix) box in a space with three or more dimensions, without using cross products?

I'm writing a computer program that needs to do this test many times and speed is very important.

I was looking at the separating axis theorem, but apparently the algorithm requires calculating the cross product of every linearly-independent normal of the first box with every linearly-independent normal of the second box, to find the (hyper)plane of separation.

This is fine in 3D, where you need nine cross-products, but in say, 10D, this would be 100 tests, which wouldn't be too bad except the hyper-spacial equivalent of the cross product requires solving a system of linear equations, so an algorithm that avoids cross products should be a lot faster.

Algorithms specific to 3D are fine. I'll figure out how to extend it to an arbitrary number of dimensions if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. In place of the cross product, which gives you a perpendicular vector, I can use the formula for a coplanar vector, which is simply $\mathbf{b} \times (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})$, which can be rewritten as $\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}) - \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a})$. Since I go through every orthogonal axis anyway, it makes no difference whether the resulting vector is perpendicular or coplanar, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: Perhaps this is equivalent to your approach, but some face (in 3D, analog in higher dimensions) of two boxes (possibly not on an axis alignment) suffice to check for (hyper)planes of separation.  Of course if one box is axis aligned, it makes sense to check its faces first (in parallel pairs) for separation from the corners of the other box.  Then if your "invertible square matrix" that orients the other box is an orthogonal matrix (required to preserve boxiness!), its inverse is its transpose and you can do the check the other way easily.

Comment: Actually, although checking the faces is necessary, checking the faces alone is not sufficient. An example of where this would fail is having two box edges criss-cross each other, oriented as if trying to cleave each other. And there is no requirement for orthogonality in the matrices. Although I didn't know that an orthogonal matrix's inverse is its transpose, so thanks for that.

Comment: The other "quick-and-dirty" trick to keep in mind is bounding (hyper)spheres around each box.  If sum of radii exceeds the center-to-center distance of boxes, there is no intersection.